# Count multiple associated models in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 models defined, Companies, Projects and Users.
Companies has many Projects and Users, so Projects and users has one company.

The problem that i am facing is when i try to count how many users and projects a company has, i get wrong results, somehow querying multiple associations is modifying the value of each other.

This is the models association:

```
    CompaniesModel.hasMany(AppUsersModel)
    AppUsersModel.belongsTo(CompaniesModel)

    CompaniesModel.hasMany(ProjectsModel)
    ProjectsModel.belongsTo(CompaniesModel)
```

This is where i try to query the count of Users and Projects for each Company:

```
    const companiesInfo = await models.companies.findAll({
        attributes: {
            include: [
                [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("projects.id")), "projectsCount"],
                [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("app_users.id")), "usersCount"],
            ],
        },
        include: [
            { model: models.projects, attributes: [] },
            { model: models.app_users, attributes: [] },
        ],
        group: ['companies.id']
    })
```

SQL Query produced:

```
SELECT `companies`.`id`, COUNT(`projects`.`id`) AS `projectsCount`, COUNT(`app_users`.`id`) AS `usersCount` FROM `companies` AS `companies` LEFT OUTER JOIN `projects` AS `projects` ON `companies`.`id` = `projects`.`companyId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `app_users` AS `app_users` ON `companies`.`id` = `app_users`.`companyId` GROUP BY `companies`.`id`
```

With this query i expected to get an array of companies like this:

```
[
    {name: companyX, usersCount: 1, projectsCount: 2},
    {name: companyY, usersCount: 5, projectsCount: 1},
    ...
]
```

But what i am getting is almost what i want but for some reasons the values are being multiplied by each other, for example:

```
[
    {name: companyX, usersCount: 2, projectsCount: 2},
    {name: companyY, usersCount: 5, projectsCount: 5},
    ...
]
```

This is what i get event though companyX only has 1 user and companyY only has 1 project, but it seems to me that, in the case of companyX, usersCount is being multiplied by projectsCount.

For instance if companyX has 2 users and 2 projects i will get the following results:

```
[
    {name: companyX, usersCount: 4, projectsCount: 4},
    ...
]
```

I would be grateful for any insight in to a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a distinct count if you are counting 2 columns in the same query.

```js
include: [
    [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.fn("DISTINCT", sequelize.col("projects.id"))), "projectsCount"],
    [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.fn("DISTINCT", sequelize.col("app_users.id"))), "usersCount"],
],
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the issue. I get it now that if you are counting more than 1 column it need to be distinct even though they are different columns